# Can't install Ubuntu onto internal hdd from usb

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

**Solved**
*see answers below*

I am trying to install version 22.04.1 LTS of Ubuntu desktop from a bootable usb onto my laptop's internal hdd. I completely want to replace Windows. My laptop has a 750GB hdd and I am using a usb of 4GB, those two drives are the only available options I have, I am learning

Some context: Windows 10 became corrupted due to some bad shutdowns, tried everything from recovery mode to fixing system files with sfc scan through cmd, dism repair, chkdsk etc. Nothing worked, so I decided to install and use Ubuntu as my OS

From my corrupted windows environment I managed to:

- Managed to boot into safe mode with networking, white screen corrupted desktop environment
- Managed to access Google Chrome app through task manager, downloaded Rufus and Ubuntu ISO, created bootable usb

Then I restarted laptop and the Ubuntu install process began, I continued with the process until reaching Installation Type

- Selected "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", not enough space, continued anyways, install failed, Ubuntu desktop environment, found Disks app, erased stuff from windows space on hdd, mistake after mistake
- Powered down laptop, reboot, usb still plugged in, no device detected to boot, research online through phone, learned about legacy mode, safe boot disable, etc

Seems everything got further corrupted now including bootable usb, so I borrowed another laptop and repeated the process

- Download ISO again, download balenaEtcher this time, created bootable usb, boot up original laptop again, success again, installation begins again

Now when I reached Installation Type again, this time I select the option Something else:

/dev/sda,
free space 1089MB,
/dev/sda4 ntfs 705092MB unknown,
free space 43974MB

/dev/sdb,
/dev/sdb1 3822MB unknown,
/dev/sdb2 4MB unknown,
/dev/sdb3 0MB unknown,
free space 100MB

options for Device for boot loader installation:
/dev/sda ATA TOSHIBA 750GB,
/dev/sda4,
/dev/sdb Kingston 4GB

I continue as per some research online:

- Select free space from above of 43974MB, click +, create partition of 1000MB for EFI System Partition, Primary, Beginning of this space
- Select free space again, click +, create partition of 6000MB for swap area, Logical, Beginning of this space
- Select free space again, click +, create partition of remainder of MB for Ext4 journaling file system, Logical, Beginning of this space, mount point /

After doing this, more options become availabe in the Device for boot loader installation menu, I choose ATA TOSHIBA 750GB (have tried other menu options as well), continue with install, install fails

"Failed to unmount partitions
The installer needs to commit changes to partition tables, but cannot do so because partitions on the following mount points could not be unmounted: /cdrom

Please close any applications using these mount points.

Would you like the installer to try to unmount these partitions again?"

I select Go Back and the process usually freezes, sometimes process resets to Installation Type, else I kill the program with ctrl+alt+T xkill

This is where I am currently stuck and I don't know what else to do. I can't seem to find anymore information searching online, most info and questions etc are not helping my case. I don't even know if what I am trying to do is possible to begin with, but I want to simply replace whatever is on the hdd and just use Ubuntu so I can get back to work and any help I appreciate!

Update: I have tried using gparted to format or erase partitions, but it won't let me do so because they first need to be unmounted. I cannot unmount them. My guess is that the bootable usb has somehow installed some form of temporary files onto the internal hdd and since any and all operations I am trying to do are not possible

Update2: I have ran a SMART test, Disk is Ok with 2255 bad sectors at 90% remaining, then it finishes with SELF-TEST FAILED. Upon short research, this doesn't always mean it can't still be used.

Comment: It's helpful if you avoid terms like *latest*, as different people see different things with it.  Do you mean Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop, ie. the 2022-October release, or an older release such as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop (ie. the older but *latest* LTS release). Did you use `gparted` to just erase the partitions prior to starting (*if I have failures, I tend to do that to resolve*), or check the drive health using SMART data?  (ie. you can't expect software to fix what are hardware issues..https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: Based on the issues you’ve reported, it sounds like the hard drive itself is toast.

Comment: @guiverc my bad, the ubuntu version is 22.04.1 LTS, I tried just now using gparted but I cannot erase (not giving me the option) nor unmount the main windows partition, says target is busy, the other two Unallocatee ones are also giving no options, I will research SMART data and get back to ya

Comment: @matigo I will check and get back to ya

Comment: @guiverc I've corrected it now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I finally solved the issue. The solution was rebooting the entire system. Here are the steps I took:

- At Installation Type I selected the option Something else
- Then I selected the option to create new partition table of the entire space from the hdd, this converted the space into ext4 type for ubuntu
- Then from the new free space available, I created three partitions using the + sign: one for /, one for swap area and one for EFI
- Proceeded with installation and an error occurs about "could not confirm with kernel" and chose "Ignore" (the process freezes regardless of choice here)
- Simply ignored the entire process and restarted the computer manually
- System rebooted again to installation process, this time selecting Something Else showed the previous work done by me to the partitions
- Went back one step and decided to select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" since I could not use the Install button in Something Else

That's it, the process continued from there flawlessly and I have now installed Ubuntu successfully. Have even done a couple restarts without usb inserted, working.